# How can i remove bios password

Tags: bios

How can i remove bios password in ah350 fujitsu
I do the password
I remove already the cmos battery 
And it turn out did not reset
I also do the 3 password 
But no code appear on the disable screen

Comment: Try the wrong password more than 3 times.

Comment: There’s no such thing as a Fujitsu Lifebook AH350. Is it perhaps an AH530?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1du5vQO58Y) which is for a different Fujitsu notebook model but may work anyway. It contains the following instructions:

1. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> (to enter setup) when powering on the device
2. At the password prompt, enter these three magic passwords in order, ignoring the report that they are incorrect:

   1. 3hqgo3
   2. jqw534
   3. 0qww294e
3. You will get a code of some variety that can be used to look up the master password. Write down this code. (In the video it’s "03100".)
4. Go to https://bios-pw.org/ and enter the code, take note of the master password for your notebook.
5. Restart the device, again using <kbd>F2</kbd>.
6. Use the master password to log in and clear the passwords.

If it doesn’t work, you can always still contact support, preferably with a proof of purchase.

Answer (score -1):

The most common way to reset bios password is to remove the cmos battery. In your case, make sure you remove the laptop battery out of slot first, and then remove the cmos battery out of the motherboard for at least five minutes.

Plug your laptop battery back without add the cmos battery, boot up laptop (maybe restart a few times). These steps may help to clear bios settings, including the password.

There is also another way to reset bios password, that is use cmos jumper.

https://www.biosflash.com/e/bios-cmos-reset.htm

Most laptop and notebook has a stronger protection to against theft. Therefore, bios password may not store inside the CMOS but may in another chip.

[image]

Comment: They said they tried that with no luck, read the question.

Comment: He said he do remove cmos battery but without telling how long. Moreover, I would suggest him to use cmos jumper to reset bios password as well. So what’s wrong?

Comment: @TimBerty - Are you positive the author’s device has a CMOS jumper?  This answer seems way to generalized.

Comment: In addition, the CMOS technique has been patched almost everywhere and a long time ago too - modern systems use EEPROMs to store data so the password data is not volatile. Some modern systems even use encryption (i.e. on thinkpads newer than XX30 series you can't bridge some pins when booting to reset the password).

Honestly I'd be surprised if the CMOS battery technique works these days for anything aside from resetting configurations.

Comment: Im sorry its AH530

Comment: I found this from Quora but don’t know whether it can help. Just try. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-remove-bios-password-of-Fujitsu-laptop-without-removing-battery-or-jumper